# Background hover color is shifted out of the box

Tags: html, css

Why is the hover color not 100% aligned with my image/box when I hover over it? It looks like it is moved up and right for 1px for some reason... Also how can I move the text 'Project name' and 'Project description' to the center of the box? I tried with transform and with `<center>` tags, but nothing works.

Code for gallery:

```
<div class="row no_gutter no_padding" id="projects">
        <div class="col-md-4 project_box slideanim">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="project_data">
                    <h4>Project name</h4>
                    <h5>Project description data</h5>
                </div>
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/portfolio/default.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 project_box slideanim">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="project_data">
                    <h4>Project name</h4>
                    <h5>Project description data</h5>
                </div>
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/portfolio/default.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 project_box slideanim">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="project_data">
                    <h4>Project name</h4>
                    <h5>Project description data</h5>
                </div>
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/portfolio/default.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.no_gutter > [class*='col-'] {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-right:0;
}
.no_padding {
    padding: 0;
}
.project_box{
    /*
    border:1px solid #1E88E5;
    box-sizing: border-box;*/
}

.project_data{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    color: transparent;
    user-select: none;
    /*center text horizontally and vertically*/
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);

    /*non-selectable text by mouse boxing*/
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none;   /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
    -khtml-user-select: none;    /* Konqueror */
    -moz-user-select: none;      /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none;       /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
    user-select: none;  
}

.project_data:hover{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    color: #fff;

    /*center text horizontally and vertically*/
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);

    background-color:#1E88E5;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Comment: A functional **minimal** demo would be of more use than a code dump.

Comment: Demo here https://jsfiddle.net/qormt73d/

Comment: The centering of text requires you to wrap it into a separate div within the background div, see my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

try to erase all the superfluous information from the `hover` rule(i.e. what is already in the non-hover rule), which reduces this CSS rule to this:

```
.project_data:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#1E88E5;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the parent container `position: relative`.
I'm not quite sure what the gallery is supposed to look like, but with the rules

```
.project_box{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height:0;
  }

.project_data{
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

the gallery behaves as expected.

Because absolutely positioned elements always use the next relatively positioned parent for reference, absolutely positioned block Elements always take up all the available horizontal space within the next relatively positioned parent.

Since there was no relative Element in your example, the overlay expanded across the whole body in my JsFiddle at first - I assume something similar happened on your site

All the other rules just are for cosmetic effect ;)

see JsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/7b7hfy0h/

As for your centering question: You need to use a separate div for text with your method, otherwise you'd also affect the background.

See the first example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/0pqg39Lh/

(the HTML only needs that one change, the rest can be moved around in CSS)